# Why aren't current group members displayed next to the 'like' button?

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like

I am trying to add a 'like' ('recommend') button to my site.

The facebook buttons appear on my website, but it doesn't show that 126 people are already members of the group.

I am testing to see if it works on this page.
http://www.quantummassageworks.com/indexFB.html

Here's the JavaScriptSDK:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    (function(d, s, id) 
    {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

And the code for the plugin:

```
<div class="fb-like" 
    data-href="https://www.facebook.com/groups/51418441750/" 
    data-send="true" data-layout="button_count" 
    data-width="450" data-show-faces="false" data-action="recommend">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok.. so your problem here is on of terminology I think.  One can not "LIKE" a group.  He can be a member of that group but not "LIKE" it.  In the same way - one can not "LIKE" a user.  
What you **can** do is "LIKE" a post, comment, photo, note, etc.. and also...
*drum roll please*
 [image]

### A Page!

If you have a page that represents your group you can link **it** to the like button by placing the page's URL in the `data-href` property of the like button div.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I thought I had the page that represents the group in the data-href property.

         <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/#!/groups/51418441750/"

Here's the page live:
http://www.quantummassageworks.com/indexFB.html

The 'recommend' and 'send' buttons show up, but no 126 members. I did want the faces to be 'off' to make it a bit more private, but it looks like there aren't any members.

Comment: @Scott - a group is not a page... I am not talking about a page in the internet...  in talk into about a Facebook page

Comment: Is there a way to convert a facebook group, to a facebook page, without losing members or wall posts? I understand a group is not a page. 

I would like users to be able to visit quantummassasgeworks.com and be able to see the "like" button interface for my businesses's facebook page.  It appears as if perhaps the problem is that the "page" was set up as a "group." Someone set it up for me, and people started joining. I didn't realize there were only scripts to "like" and not to "join" facebook pages (or groups).

Comment: no... I'm afraid this is not possible... you can however send a group message to your members notifying them of your new page...

Comment: Thanks. So, there is no script available to embed an interface on my website to point people to the group that already exists?

Comment: You could just put a link to the group on your page.